# fmodex returning ERR_FILE_BAD playing an MP3 file under Mono/Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, mp3, fmod

I'm trying to use fmodex 4.30.03 to play an MP3 file under Mono/Ubuntu.

My call to createSound() looks as follows:

```
result = system.createSound(path, 
    (FMOD.MODE._2D | FMOD.MODE.HARDWARE | FMOD.MODE.CREATESTREAM), 
    ref sound);
```

as per the C# examples that come with the SDK.

`result` is being set to 19, `ERR_FILE_BAD`.

The same thing works fine under Windows. I have the following in app.config:

```
<dllmap os="linux" dll="fmodex" target="./libfmodex-4.30.03.so"/>
```

If this isn't present, fmodex never even gets loaded, so I know it's getting so far.

The file I'm passing in definitely exists, but if I pass an invalid path I actually get the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you managed to get the FMOD system initialized and everything. The C# wrapper passes strings through to FMOD for createSound as unicode which FMOD doesn't support on Linux. To fix this you will need to alter the C# wrapper, remove the FMOD_UNICODE flag being passed in and ensure the strings being fed into FMOD are normal ASCII.

Comment: Thanks - I posed on their forum and got this answer, which worked fine.